# Can I exclude Google Books result from Google Search?

Tags: google-search

I googled several random keywords and gave me undesired result like this below :
[image: No, I don't want books]

There were Google Books results (undesired). I tried `-site:books.google.co.in` but they were still exist.
How can I get rid of them so they don't show up on Google Search?

Comment: At the screenshot I know that Google Books results had no green URL link (if using Opera Mini), there were also name of author(s) and page count. All of those results had no descriptions at all.

Comment: I assumed that I was in Indonesia and I used Indonesian version of Google (google.co.id). I hope you can replicate my case.

Answer (score 1):

The links are listed in green under each search result, and non of them have any relation to google books. They are just matches for your keywords out there in the internet.
If you don’t want those, you can either scroll down for the ones you like, or find a way of defining what you ‘*don’t want*’ (which is *not* google books), then you can remove those.

Comment: Should I used -site:books.google.co.id? If my problem still persist, I'd like to have a report to Google itself.

Answer (score 0):

Append `-books` to your query, i.e. `iso 2000 -books`.

Explanation

Google classifies content using a **knowledge graph**. This is used to feed **knowledge panels** but also to make that certain keywords triggers special behaviors. One of those behaviors is related to books. For details, read [Find books on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/11459602?hl=en).

Resources

- [How Google's Knowledge Graph works](https://support.google.com/knowledgepanel/answer/9787176?hl=en)

Related

- [Where to find a list of Google search operators?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/122235/88163)